# Retrieve data from JSON?

Tags: python, json

I'm new in python and need get a value fron anoter value of same block, this is an example of JSON:

```
{
  u'Name': u'test',
  u'ProjectPath': u'/data/compose/test_pz4u6zug8swd2isfkcrzh9kjl',
  u'ResourceControl': {
    u'ResourceId': u'test',
    u'UserAccesses': [

    ],
    u'AdministratorsOnly': True,
    u'TeamAccesses': [

    ],
    u'SubResourceIds': [

    ],
    u'Type': 6,
    u'Id': 8
  },
  u'EntryPoint': u'docker-compose.yml',
  u'Env': [

  ],
  u'SwarmId': u'pz4u6zug8swd2isfkcrzh9kjl',
  u'Id': u'test_pz4u6zug8swd2isfkcrzh9kjl'
},
{
  u'Name': u'ycf',
  u'ProjectPath': u'/data/compose/ycf_pz4u6zug8swd2isfkcrzh9kjl',
  u'ResourceControl': {
    u'ResourceId': u'ycf',
    u'UserAccesses': [

    ],
    u'AdministratorsOnly': True,
    u'TeamAccesses': [

    ],
    u'SubResourceIds': [

    ],
    u'Type': 6,
    u'Id': 5
  },
  u'EntryPoint': u'docker-compose.yml',
  u'Env': None,
  u'SwarmId': u'pz4u6zug8swd2isfkcrzh9kjl',
  u'Id': u'ycf_pz4u6zug8swd2isfkcrzh9kjl'
}
```

I need get the value of `Id` from filed `Name`, eg. I need to know value of `Id` (`test_pz4u6zug8swd2isfkcrzh9kjl`) from `Name` 'test', is possible?

I get this JSON from a request:

```
r_get = requests.get(http://www.example.com:9000/api/endpoints/1/stacks)
id_response = json.loads(r_get.content.decode('utf-8'))
print(id_response)
```

Comment: I assume the JSON is coming in, in an array? Just missing the `[]` from the example?

Comment: The input is not valid json (use [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) to test). Looks like an excerpt of a Python repr.

Comment: It looks like what you posted is not your JSON, but the Python objects you get back from `json.loads`. Which is fine, but your question needs to be clear. If you tell us you're giving one thing and instead give us something else, instead of the answers you need, you're going to get comments like the two above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cycle through all your records and look for the first case where `Name` matches your desired value.

```
for element in id_response:
    if element[u'Name'] == u'test':
        my_id = element[u'Id']
        break
else:
    # will only get here if we never break from the loop
    raise ValueError('No element named "test"')

print(my_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the result is a list of dictionaries, you can use a comprehension to rearrange the data:

```
id_for_name = {item[u'Name']: item[u'Id'] for item in id_response}

print(id_for_name)
# {u'test': u'test_pz4u6zug8swd2isfkcrzh9kjl', u'ycf': u'ycf_pz4u6zug8swd2isfkcrzh9kjl'}
print(id_for_name['test'])
# test_pz4u6zug8swd2isfkcrzh9kjl
```